# ndk finished with non-zero exit value 69

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i am learning ndk in android.I got a problem.
here is error info:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.

```
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/yishuaiqin/Documents/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build'' **finished with non-zero exit value 69**
```

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        ndk{
            moduleName "JniDemo"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

I tried to add

```
sourceSets.main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/JniDemo']
        jni.srcDirs = [] // This prevents the auto generation of Android.mk
    }
```

but i will happen another error,this:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication, PID: 19774
                                                                                      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.android.tools.fd.runtime.IncrementalClassLoader$DelegateClassLoader[DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-23.4.0_a08614bb6283cfa324b87685191afbfb59aca883-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-23.4.0_d3bbf4c848f2f380fb4656d172d460d67e20c13a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-23.4.0_349aae7a307baa89345a2ee68f546bcfc06d7dcb-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-23.4.0_1345311585f1d2a3e686ce5b1400b7695dd6eb16-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-23.4.0_f833b9499bab0649a8dfe39f8821365db78812c6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0_1ce53af57ba1082cd25ff52df7ce61dddbd9cdad-classes.dex"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libJniDemo.so"
                                                                                          at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
                                                                                          at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
                                                                                          at com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication.NdkTest.<clinit>(NdkTest.java:10)
                                                                                          at com.example.yishuaiqin.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                                                                                          at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I tried solutions in other answers,but not help me.
Anyone has any idea? Thanks at advance.

Comment: the best way to fix this is to disable Android Studio's limited NDK support and call ndk-build from gradle script.

Comment: if the above option doesnt work check path local.properties for ndk  is set like `ndk.dir=C\:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\ndk`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are MacOS user, check your XCode if there is no need to agree the latest license agreement. Until you run the XCode and agree with license, it will block ndk task, as it use tools included in XCode distribution.